# on body click run one function after another click run another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to Call one function after click on body then call different function after the second click?

i tried and then stopped, any ideas?

```
$("html, body").one("click",function() {
  // to something
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create click once and double click functionality?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: i want to change background image when clicked on body, then after click change background again, after that launch a different function

Comment: It would help if you edit your question and explain in better detail what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this:

```
var clicks = 0;
$("html, body").on("click",function() {
    if(clicks === 0){
        funcA();
    } 
    if(clicks > 1){
        funcB();
    }
    clicks++;
}
```

Where `funcA` and `func`

Comment: You cannot use `.one()` in your answer.  The first click will fire and that's it, no other events will fire including another click.  Consider using `.on()`

Comment: One will execute once per element. Did you mean .on?

Comment: @Christos No problem, it happens :).  This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I changed my answer due to your latest addition to your question.
See this snippet:

```js
var myFunctions = [];

myFunctions.push(function() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "red");
});

myFunctions.push(function() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "green");
});

$("html, body").click(function(){
  if(myFunctions.length > 0) myFunctions.shift()();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

html part :

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" />
```

script part:

```
$("input").one("click",function() {
    alert("First Function");  
  $("input").one("click",function() {
    alert("Second Function");
  });
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/goldenfinger/zox6orb8/)

Comment: I don't understand the use of input in this case. Isn't it easier to add event listener on body?

Comment: Yes you can, just to show case the demo i added the input. In place of input you can add any selector.